# how to convert each element in 2 list to separate dictionary react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

hello i have a list which have all country code i want to convert them into separate dict like the example below

code list

this is name list

```
(169) ["Af", "al", "dz", "ao", "Ar", "Am", "Au", "At", "Az", "ds", "bh", "Bd", "bb", "by", "be", "bz", "bj", "bt", "bo", "da", "bw", "br", "bn", "bg", "bf", "Bi", "cv", "kh", "cm", "ca", "cf", "td", "cl", "cn", "co", "km", "cg", "cr", "ci", "hr", "cu", "cy", "Cz", "cod", "dk", "Dj", "do", "Ec", "Eg", "Sv", "gq", "er", "ee", "swz", "et", "Fj", "fi", "fr", "ga", "gm", "Ge", "de", "gh", "Gr", "gt", "gn", "gw", "gy", "ht", "hn", "iu", "is", "in", "id", "ir", "ie", "il", "it", "jm", "jp", "jo", "kz", "ke", "kw", "kg", "la", "lv", "lb", "ls", "lr", "ly", "lt", "lu", "mg", "mw", "my", "mv", "ml", "mt", "mr", …]
```

this is value list

```
const value = [
    '11 000',
    '1400 [730–2800]',
    '22 000 [10 000–32 000]',
    '340 000 [290 000–410 000]',
    '140 000 [120 000–160 000]',
    '3500 [2900–4500]',
    '29 000 [21 000–38 000]',
    'No data',
    '9700 [7300–13 000]',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    '2700 [1300–4700]',
    '28 000 [22 000–36 000]',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    '75 000 [50 000–110 000]',
    'No data',
    '19 000 [16 000–23 000]',
    'No data',
    '380 000 [340 000–410 000]',
    '920 000 [420 000–1 300 000]',
    'No data',
    '3300 [3000–3700]',
    '100 000 [84 000–120 000]',
    '85 000 [73 000–100 000]',
    '2500 [2100–3000]',
    '73 000 [63 000–84 000]',
    '510 000 [450 000–560 000]',
    'No data',
    '100 000 [84 000–130 000]',
    '120 000 [94 000–140 000]',
    '74 000 [64 000–85 000]',
    'No data',
    '200 000 [160 000–250 000]',
    '130 [<100–<500]',
    '100 000 [78 000–140 000]',
    '14 000 [11 000–18 000]',
    '430 000 [370 000–500 000]',
    '1600 [1100–2100]',
    '32 000 [20 000–47 000]',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    '520 000 [420 000–640 000]',
    'No data',
    '6800 [4900–10 000]',
    '72 000 [58 000–88 000]',
    '47 000 [35 000–78 000]',
    '26 000 [19 000–34 000]',
    '27 000 [23 000–32 000]',
    '65 000 [48 000–88 000]',
    '14 000 [10 000–19 000]',
    'No data',
    '200 000 [190 000–220 000]',
    '670 000 [510 000–860 000]',
    '1000 [670–2200]',
    'No data',
    '190 000 [160 000–220 000]',
    '51 000 [38 000–66 000]',
    '28 000 [22 000–36 000]',
    '9100 [5700–15 000]',
    'No data',
    '340 000 [250 000–460 000]',
    'No data',
    '36 000 [31 000–44 000]',
    '110 000 [95 000–130 000]',
    '40 000 [35 000–46 000]',
    '8700 [7800–9700]',
    '160 000 [130 000–180 000]',
    '25 000 [21 000–29 000]',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    '59 000 [33 000–130 000]',
    '7500 [6200–8800]',
    'No data',
    '130 000 [71 000–210 000]',
    '32 000 [26 000–44 000]',
    'No data',
    'No data',
    '33 000 [30 000–38 000]',
    '1 500 000 [1 300 000–1 700 000]',
    'No data',
    '10 000 [9700–10 000]',
    '13 000 [12 000–15 000]',
    '5600 [3500–7400]',
    '2700 [1500–4300]',
    '340 000 [320 000–360 000]',
    '47 000 [37 000–59 000]',
    '9500 [7200–12 000]',
    '3400 [2900–4000]',
    'No data',
    '39 000 [32 000–49 000]',
    '1 100 000 [960 000–1 100 000]',
    '88 000 [78 000–98 000]',
    'No data',
    '140 000 [120 000–180 000]',
    'No data',
    '5700 [4200–8300]',
];
```

i want to convert them like

```
 const data = [
{country: af, value: "11000"},
{country: al, value: "1400"},
{country: dz, value: "22000"}.......
```

]

it would be very helpful to have a solution to this.. i have been looking for solution for a long time.. i want a dictionay like the example above. when i try it is loading all the data in one array

Comment: How are you pairing the county code with the value? where did the space go? what about the numbers in brackets? What happens with 'No data'? This seems like something that would be simple to do with a for loop; have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

This can be achieved using `map` method which is described as "*The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.*"

In this case the provide function is:

```
(currentValue, index) => ({'country': countryList[index], 'value': currentValue})
```

Note: make sure to validate that both are of same size or if not what to do.

**Putting it altogether:**

```js
const countryList = ["Af", "al", "dz", "ao", "Ar", "Am", "Au", "At", "Az", "ds", "bh", "Bd", "bb", "by", "be", "bz", "bj", "bt", "bo", "da", "bw", "br", "bn", "bg", "bf", "Bi", "cv", "kh", "cm", "ca", "cf", "td", "cl", "cn", "co", "km", "cg", "cr", "ci", "hr", "cu", "cy", "Cz", "cod", "dk", "Dj", "do", "Ec", "Eg", "Sv", "gq", "er", "ee", "swz", "et", "Fj", "fi", "fr", "ga", "gm", "Ge", "de", "gh", "Gr", "gt", "gn", "gw", "gy", "ht", "hn", "iu", "is", "in", "id", "ir", "ie", "il", "it", "jm", "jp", "jo", "kz", "ke", "kw", "kg", "la", "lv", "lb", "ls", "lr", "ly", "lt", "lu", "mg", "mw", "my", "mv", "ml", "mt", "mr"];

const value = [
  '11 000',
  '1400 [730–2800]',
  '22 000 [10 000–32 000]',
  '340 000 [290 000–410 000]',
  '140 000 [120 000–160 000]',
  '3500 [2900–4500]',
  '29 000 [21 000–38 000]',
  'No data',
  '9700 [7300–13 000]',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  '2700 [1300–4700]',
  '28 000 [22 000–36 000]',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  '75 000 [50 000–110 000]',
  'No data',
  '19 000 [16 000–23 000]',
  'No data',
  '380 000 [340 000–410 000]',
  '920 000 [420 000–1 300 000]',
  'No data',
  '3300 [3000–3700]',
  '100 000 [84 000–120 000]',
  '85 000 [73 000–100 000]',
  '2500 [2100–3000]',
  '73 000 [63 000–84 000]',
  '510 000 [450 000–560 000]',
  'No data',
  '100 000 [84 000–130 000]',
  '120 000 [94 000–140 000]',
  '74 000 [64 000–85 000]',
  'No data',
  '200 000 [160 000–250 000]',
  '130 [<100–<500]',
  '100 000 [78 000–140 000]',
  '14 000 [11 000–18 000]',
  '430 000 [370 000–500 000]',
  '1600 [1100–2100]',
  '32 000 [20 000–47 000]',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  '520 000 [420 000–640 000]',
  'No data',
  '6800 [4900–10 000]',
  '72 000 [58 000–88 000]',
  '47 000 [35 000–78 000]',
  '26 000 [19 000–34 000]',
  '27 000 [23 000–32 000]',
  '65 000 [48 000–88 000]',
  '14 000 [10 000–19 000]',
  'No data',
  '200 000 [190 000–220 000]',
  '670 000 [510 000–860 000]',
  '1000 [670–2200]',
  'No data',
  '190 000 [160 000–220 000]',
  '51 000 [38 000–66 000]',
  '28 000 [22 000–36 000]',
  '9100 [5700–15 000]',
  'No data',
  '340 000 [250 000–460 000]',
  'No data',
  '36 000 [31 000–44 000]',
  '110 000 [95 000–130 000]',
  '40 000 [35 000–46 000]',
  '8700 [7800–9700]',
  '160 000 [130 000–180 000]',
  '25 000 [21 000–29 000]',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  '59 000 [33 000–130 000]',
  '7500 [6200–8800]',
  'No data',
  '130 000 [71 000–210 000]',
  '32 000 [26 000–44 000]',
  'No data',
  'No data',
  '33 000 [30 000–38 000]',
  '1 500 000 [1 300 000–1 700 000]',
  'No data',
  '10 000 [9700–10 000]',
  '13 000 [12 000–15 000]',
  '5600 [3500–7400]',
  '2700 [1500–4300]',
  '340 000 [320 000–360 000]',
  '47 000 [37 000–59 000]',
  '9500 [7200–12 000]',
  '3400 [2900–4000]',
  'No data',
  '39 000 [32 000–49 000]',
  '1 100 000 [960 000–1 100 000]',
  '88 000 [78 000–98 000]',
  'No data',
  '140 000 [120 000–180 000]',
  'No data',
  '5700 [4200–8300]',
];


const output = value.map((currentValue, index) => ({
  'country': countryList[index],
  'value': currentValue
}));

console.log(output);
```